# dw 1820 a Linux wifi (not work)

Tags: debian, wifi, драйвер

Не реботает wifi на Deepin 15.11

---

sudo lshw -C network

```html
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 2c:56:dc:bc:2d:15
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:dfa04000-dfa04fff memory:dfa00000-dfa03fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 08
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df800000-df807fff memory:df400000-df7fffff
```

---

dmesg | grep brcm

```html
[   21.476296] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd failed with error -2
[   21.476300] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd not found
```

---

lspci

```html
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 08)
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо установить пакет с прошивками: `apt-get install firmware-brcm80211`

В «чистом» дебиане для этого необходимо предварительно подключить `non-free`, для случая вашего дистрибутива читайте руководство по нему.

Если wi-fi — единственный сетевой интерфейс, то придётся нужный .deb скачать ручками с другого компьютера, перенести на требуемый и установить через `dpkg -i`